# Music keeps pausing

Tags: music, music-player, google-play-music, spotify

So I am using a nexus 7 with Autodroid 1.2 (4.4.4)

For about 1 month its been fine, but lately my music will start randomly pausing and then when I click play it will instantly pause again and I have no idea why. Now this is happening in every app that can play music: Spotify, Google Music, etc

This also happens when I am currently in the app or if I am on the launcher screen.
"Ok Google" is also turned off

Another note, the tablet is in flight mode, so it has no wifi, 3G or bluetooth turned on

Is there a way to figure out what keeps causing it to pause so I can stop it?

Comment: This seems more like your Spotify account is in use somewhere else - you can only use it on one device at a time.

Are you sure you are the only one using it?

Comment: @David As I stated in the question, this is happening in every music player, not just spotify. Also the tablet has no internet connected so even if it was, it wouldn't affect it

Answer (score 1):

I once had that problem with a previous Android phone.

The problem turned out to be my earbuds. They (or perhaps the connector) were going bad, and apparently sending extra signals through the headset jack that were being interpreted as music controls. Some headsets have music controls on them, after all.

So the first thing I'd suggest is try playing it without any headset plugged in, and see if the problem goes away.